# Powershell 5.1 launches any console command on new console window

Tags: windows, powershell

I have quite strange behavior happening on my powershell code. I pinned it down to these simple reproduceable steps.

1. Launch Powershell as Administrator.
2. Type `cmd` and confirm it opens `cmd` on the current Powershell terminal. Type `exit` to get out of the `cmd` console.
3. Run the following code:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
cd iis:\apppools

new-item c:\temp\1 -itemType directory
Push-Location
cd c:\temp\1
Pop-Location
remove-item c:\temp\1
```

4. Type `cmd` and now you see it opens `cmd` on a new window.
5. Run `cd c:\`
6. Type `cmd` and now you see it opens `cmd` on a current window as expected.
7. Run `cd iis:\apppools`, and then `cmd`, and you see it opens on a current window as expected.

**Why did #4 open in new window, and then why does `cd c:\` fix the problem?**

The real problem that I am dealing with is that when the console gets into the state of step #4, it launches *any* console command in a new window, so while I would expect the script to wait until the console command is finished, it launches the console command in a new window and move on to the next line without waiting for the console to finish.

Reproduceable on Powershell 5.1.14393.4350 (Windows 2016), 5.1.18362.1171 (Windows 10) and 5.1.19041.906 (Windows 10).

Comment: I don't have IIS installed, but I can't reproduce this problem with other drive providers.

Comment: When calling cmd from powershell it tries to set path to the current path that you are in however iis: (env:, alias:, cert:, etc) are not available paths in cmd.  It tries instead to fallback to the previous folder which you've deleted.  It appears that the failsafe for this in the code is to open a real cmd window instead.  This can be replicated without iis, push-location and pop-location.  `mkdir c:\temp\deleteme; cd c:\temp\deleteme; cd env:; rm c:\temp\deleteme -Recurse; cmd`

Comment: @Daniel that makes sense. Thank you for looking into this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Daniel's comment had the answer:

When calling cmd from powershell, it tries to set path to the current path that you are in. However, iis: (env:, alias:, cert:, etc) are not available paths in cmd. So it will try to fallback to the latest folder you were in under cmd-accessible path (C:, D:\ etc.)

And when the folder does not exist, it appears that the failsafe for this in the code is to open a real cmd window instead.

This can be replicated without IIS, push-location and pop-location.

```
mkdir c:\temp\deleteme; 
cd c:\temp\deleteme; 
cd env:; 
rm c:\temp\deleteme -Recurse; 
cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel's comment had the answer, and I am writing it here to comply with StackOverflow's rule:

When calling cmd from powershell, it tries to set path to the current path that you are in. However, iis: (env:, alias:, cert:, etc) are not available paths in cmd. So it will try to fallback to the latest folder you were in under cmd-accessible path (C:, D:\ etc.)

And when the folder does not exist, it appears that the failsafe for this in the code is to open a real cmd window instead.

This can be replicated without IIS, push-location and pop-location.

```
mkdir c:\temp\deleteme; 
cd c:\temp\deleteme; 
cd env:; 
rm c:\temp\deleteme -Recurse; 
cmd
```